# Does Microsoft Windows Act as Intermediary for Android Text Messages or Push Notifications?

Tags: windows, android, iphone, microsoft-edge, multi-factor-authentication

I have many 2FA enabled accounts tied to sending a text, unfortunately they don't push to authenticator apps, yet.

When using macOS such codes are discoverable in the notification area, and when I'm using the Safari branded browsers these codes fill in for into the appropriate browser cell and often will automatically submit the form to move along as authenticated.

I know Windows does not interact with iMessage or SMS from iPhones, but does it for Android? Is the experience similar to that of iPhones on macOS?

I would test this but lack the hardware to do so.

Comment: As far as I know only if you connect the phone via USB to Windows and use the MS YourPhone app. Then notifications will be shown on Windows, too.

Comment: Yuck. I hope it’s not like this in Winsider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the basic functionality of receiving SMS messages, viewing gallery photos, and [notifications](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/setting-up-notifications-in-the-your-phone-app-0ad015d9-0c9c-6d0c-f67c-be0538459f18), [Your Phone](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/your-phone-app-requirements-and-set-up-cd2a1ee7-75a7-66a6-9d4e-bf22e735f9e3) when used with [Your Phone Companion](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.appmanager&hl=en_AU&gl=US) supports any Android 7.0+ device.

Some more advanced functionality, including screen sharing and remote viewing of Android apps, require [Link to Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/supported-devices-for-your-phone-app-experiences-cb044172-87aa-9e41-d446-c4ac83ce8807) which is only supported on some Surface and Samsung devices at this moment.

Comment: Cool, never heard of Link